# Real Analysis: if the integral of the cube of a function exists, does it follow that the integral of the function also exists?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=[a,b]$. Given that $\int_a^bf^3(x)\;dx$ exists, does it follow that  $\int_a^bf(x)\;dx$ exists?

Let's let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers.

Comment: Do you mean the Riemann integral?

Comment: Are a and b understood to be finite?

Comment: Yes, a and b are finite. I can come up with a counter example if you let b = infinity. f(x) = 1/x

Comment: The integral could be Riemann or Darboux. Same thing.

Comment: I've tried to find a counter example using Bertrand integrals and no luck. I'm not even sure now if I think the answer is yes or no, much less how to prove it.

Comment: Well, the claim is false if you have an infinite interval (just take f(x) = $\frac{1}{x}$.   But you can change, say, the interval [1, $\infty$] into a finite interval by, say, switching variables to z, where x = tan(z).

Comment: Took me annoyingly many tries, but I finally sorted out the $\infty$. Too stubborn to look it up.

Comment: If the domain is finite (it is in your case), then doesn't $L^{3}([a,b])\subset L^{2}([a,b])\subset L^{1}([a,b])$?

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, but could you explain a tad more as to how you made the interval finite?

Comment: Consider $\int_ 1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$.  Change variable via tan(z) = x to get $\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{sec^2 z}{tanz} dx = 2 $$\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{dz}{sin 2z}$.  Granted, the integrand is badly singular at one endpoint, and perhaps you don't want to allow that type of improper integral.

Comment: Transforming the interval $[1, \infty)$ to a finite one may not work because of the chain rule. The integrands in $z$-space corresponding to $\int_{1}^{\infty} 1/x^3 dx$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} 1/x dx$ will not be $g^3(z)$ and $g(z)$, but something else.

Comment: Ah, that is true.  Good point.  I'll have to work harder...

Comment: @lulu Riemann integral is only defined on bounded closed intervals.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint (for a solution not using measure theory).**

If you know a statement that says: if $g$ is continuous and $f$ is Riemann-integrable then $g \circ f$ is Riemann-integrable, you're done!

If not, you can try to prove it with following steps:

1. If $f$ is Riemann-integrable and $g$ Lipschitz then $g \circ f$ is Riemann-integrable.
2. A continuous function defined on a compact segment $[a,b]$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of piecewise linear functions.
3. A piecewise linear function is Lipschitz.
4. Conclude based on 1, 2 and 3.

You can simplify a bit this general statement for your $g: x \to x^{1/3}$, but I think that it is more valuable for you to prove the general statement as it let you understand deeper what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is true if $[a,b]$ is a finite interval. We may assume without loss of generality that $f \geq 0$ on this interval, as the integral of measurable function exists only if its "positive" and "negative" parts do.

Let $S = \{ x \in [a,b] : f(x) \leq 1 \}$. Notice that for any $s \in S^C$, $ \, \,f(s) \leq f(s)^3$, since $f(s) > 1$. Then
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx = \int_{S} f(x) \, dx + \int_{S^C} f(x) \, dx \leq  \int_{S} \, dx + \int_{S^C} f(x)^3 \, dx
$$
Note that here we have used the fact that on $S$, $f \leq 1$. But since $f^3$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $S \cup S^{C} = [a,b]$,
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx \leq (b-a) + \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^3 \,dx < \infty.
$$

Thus $f$ is integrable on this domain.

(Sidebar: Here I've been using the Lebesgue integral, but provided $f$ is nice enough, (Super secret sidebar: I think just continuous) $S$ and $S^C$ should just be the union of intervals, so this would also work for the Riemann integral.)

Comment: I like it! But, why is it true that I can take f ≥ 0 ?  It is not true, for example, that an (infinite) sum converges iff its positive terms and negative terms separately converge.

Comment: In the definition of the Lebesgue integral, we say that a function $f$ is integrable if and only if the functions $\max\{(f(x),0\}$ and $-\min\{f(x),0 \}. This allows us to assume our function is non-negative. If it were not, then the max and min functions would be.

Comment: As for the infinite sum, it will if its absolutely convergent. And the Lebesgue integral is analogous to absolutely convergent sums, precisely for this reason / definition.

Comment: You prove here that IF $f$ is integrable, then its integral is less than something. But you don't prove that $f$ is integrable. You write $\int f_a^b f(x)dx$ without proving first that this symbol makes sense.

Comment: Did we establish that this was a Lebesgue question?  We can make a step function counterexample: divide [0,1] into subintervals, the $i^{th}$ subinterval having length $L_i$.  Let f = $\frac{a_i}{L_i}$ on the $i^{th}$ interval, where $\sum a_i$ is your favorite conditionally convergent series (absolutely divergent).  Then the improper integral, taken as a limit in the usual way, just gives you the conditionally convergent series.  Again, the questioner may not want to allow such improper integrals.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The expression $\int f dx$ will make sense because we are integrating a non-negative function. It's the supremum of $\int g dx$ where $g$ is a bounded measurable function with finite-measure support so that $0 \leq g \leq f$. This supremum will always exist, but it may be infinite. The monotonicity still works with infinite limits. All we have shown is that this supremum is finite, and so $f$ is integrable.

Comment: @Bryan Are you working with Lebesgue or Riemann integral ? And if you're working with Lebesgue integral, what is your argument to prove that $f$ is measurable?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The Lebesgue, but I think you can patch it for the Riemann from this.The map $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is increasing,  so $\{x: f(x)^3 > \alpha^3 \}  = \{x: f(x) > \alpha \}.$  The former set is measurable since $f^3$ is integrable and so $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using "a gun to kill a fly" (straight translation of a French sentence).**

According to Lebesgue criteria a function is Riemann integrable if and only if the measure of the set of its discontinuity points is zero. As $x \to x^3$ is continuous as its inverse function, the measure of the set discontinuity points of $f^3$ is the same as the one of $f$. Hence $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely a way to do it without using measure theory or Lebesgue anything because I am finding this question in an undergrad intro real analysis text, chapter five.....

Comment: I posted a second answer using less sophisticated means to catch the fly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary  proof, using just the definition of Riemann integrability:

Write $f^3(x)=:g(x)$. We may assume $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $\bigl|g(x)\bigr|\leq1$, since $g$ is Riemann integrable. Given any subinterval $J\subset[0,1]$ write $$\|\Delta g\|_J:=\sup_{x,y\in J}\bigl|g(y)-g(x)\bigr|\ ,$$ and denote the length of $J$ by $|J|$.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. By assumption there is a partition of $[0,1]$ into finitely many subintervals $J_k$ such that
$$\sum_k\|\Delta g\|_{J_k}\>|J_k|\leq\epsilon^4\ .\tag{1}$$
Call a $k$  *bad* if $\|\Delta g\|_{J_k}\>\geq\epsilon^3$ and *good* otherwise. From $(1)$ it then follows that
$$\sum_{k\>{\rm bad}}|J_k|<\epsilon\ .$$
Looking at the graph of the function $t\mapsto{\root 3\of t}$ (defined on all of ${\mathbb R}$ and having a sign) we see that
$$\bigl|{\root 3\of u}-{\root 3\of v}\bigr|\leq2^{2/3}|u-v|^{1/3}\qquad(u,v\in{\mathbb R})\ .$$
From this we conclude that
$$\|\Delta f\|_{J_k}\leq2^{2/3}\|\Delta g\|_{J_k}^{1/3}<2\epsilon\qquad(k\ {\rm good})\ ,$$
so that we obtain
$$\sum_k \|\Delta f\|_{J_k}\>|J_k|=\sum_{k\>{\rm good}} \|\Delta f\|_{J_k}\>|J_k|+\sum_{k\>{\rm bad}} \|\Delta f\|_{J_k}\>|J_k|\leq2\epsilon\cdot 1+2\cdot\epsilon=4\epsilon\ .$$
As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary this proves that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

Basic result: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R,$ then $g\circ f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$ Apply this to your problem with $g(x) = x^{1/3}.$